# scroll view doesnt scroll as expected

Tags: android, xml, view, scroll

In my xml layout I have 2 separate layouts in the same file, a grid of pictures and then a full screen image view. The issue is that the grid of pictures scrolls down to the bottom but not all the way to the top, the pictures are cut off. I am not sure why this would happen, here is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/full_image"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#00000000">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Return"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TitleText3"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"/>

    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"
            android:max="26"
            android:longClickable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rows">



<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        >


    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="0"
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane1"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane3"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane4"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row2">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane5"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane6"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane7"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image8"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane8"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row3">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image9"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane9"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image10"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane10"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image11"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane11"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image12"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane12"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row4">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image13"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane13"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image14"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane14"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image15"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane15"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image16"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane16"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row5">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image17"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane17"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image18"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane18"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image19"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane19"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image20"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane20"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row6">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image21"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane21"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image22"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane22"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image23"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane23"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image24"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plane24"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row8">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image25"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane25"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image26"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane26"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/row8">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image27"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/plane25"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image28"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@drawable/plane26"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you use fill_parent for the scrollview dimensions. is there a specific reason for that? I tend to use match_parent or wrap_content and I don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a `LinearLayout` tag at the end.

You start the file with a parent LinearLayout declaration, and never have an ending `</LinearLayout>` tag to match it.

Try adding `</LinearLayout>` to the very end, right after `</ScrollView>`.

Comment: I checked my layout and it was there, it must not have copied over when i put the code on here. wouldn't the intelij tell me that was the error if that was?

Comment: Try changing your `ScrollView`'s width and height to `wrap_content`. Also do the same for the first `LinearLayout` within your `ScrollView`.

Comment: Have you considered creating a new layout with just the parent `LinearLayout` and begin adding in sections (or blocks) of the current layout in, to see what works, and then when it stops working?